# How do I access functions of an instance variable of a class, within another class?

Tags: ruby, irb

Take this for example:

```
class Inner
    attr_accessor :id, :number
    def initialize(id, number)
      @id                    = id
      @number                = number
    end
    def id()
      return @id + "_" @number
    end
end

class Outer
    attr_accessor :id, :inner, :another
    def initialize(id, inner, another)
      @id                    = id
      @inner                 = inner # instance variable for class Inner object
      @another               = another
    end
    def id()
      return "Outer id:\n"
      + @id + "\nInner : " + @inner.id() +"\nAnother: " + @another + "\n"
    end
end
```

When I call the id() function of an "Outer" object, the output stops at "\nInner : ". How do I get around this? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure 'output stops at "\nInner : "' ? I'd bet output now stops at "Outer id:" (because you return from the method on this line and the next one is never evaluated)

Comment: I think you may be missing a `+` in the Inner's id method's return -> `return @id + "_" + @number`

Comment: @Talkaboutnostalgia : Place parenthesis around the expression to be returned.

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov Actually, what you said is happening. And also, some classes like "Inner" manage to return the requested ID string, while others don't. I'm not able to find a difference between them.

Answer (score 1):

You should add on line 8 a `+` and also cast the integer value to a string with `to_s`

```rb
return @id.to_s + "_" + @number.to_s
```

On line 20 shouldn't be a line break, just put everything after `return` all on one line. There is also the same issue as it was on line 8. You have to cast the integer with .to_s to a string or put `"#{}"` around them.

```rb
return "Outer id:\n" + "#{@id}" + "\nInner : " + "#{@inner.id}" +"\nAnother: " + "#{@another}"+ "\n"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. So far, it's still not working. I'll find out how much detail I can add to the question once I speak to coworkers.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite of the code for more idiomatic ruby:

```rb
class Inner
  attr_accessor :id, :number

  def initialize(id, number)
    @id = id
    @number = number
  end

  def to_s
    "#{id}_#{number}"
  end
end

class Outer
  attr_accessor :id, :inner, :another
  def initialize(id, inner, another)
    @id = id
    @inner = inner # instance variable for class Inner object
    @another = another
  end

  def to_s
    <<~STR
      Outer id:#{id}
      Inner : #{inner}
      Another: #{another}
    STR
   # Or something like
   # [
   #   "Outer id:#{id}", 
   #   "Inner : #{inner}", 
   #   "Another: #{another}",
   # ].join("\n") + "\n"
  end
end
```

Relevant styleguide

1. Prefer `"#{var}"` over `'' + var + ''` for string interpolation to automatically cast variables as strings.
2. Don't use explicit `return` unless needed.
3. Prefer heredoc for multi-line strings (or other patterns).
4. Don't define an `attr_acessor` then redefine the method in the class. Generally I'd avoid defining a getter that doesn't return the stored variable. It looks like you want to a "stringified" representation of the class, which is commonly done with a `to_s` method.
5. Prefer instance methods over ivars.**

** This is probably more personal preference, but I find code with ivars as less refactorable than code that uses the accessor methods (since the code works the same whether it's a method argument or instance method or local variable)

Comment: Thank you for your help. So far, it's still not working. I'll find out how much detail I can add to the question once I speak to coworkers.